# Spring boot 2.2.5 release Getting 404 not found error

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to execute Spring boot application hosted on a tomcat server online. The issue is when I try to get, delete or post data, a user controller it generates this message.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-01-24T06:45:42.144+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/tool/api/v1/users"
}
```

the weird issue is that when I run the server locally `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users` I get data
but when I try hosting the war file and hitting the endpoint `http://31.134.12.356:9080/tool/api/v1/users`i end up with the error above.

My Users Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{username}")
    public User getUserByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/users")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveUser(@RequestBody SaveUserRequest userRequest) {

        //save user details
        User user = new User(userRequest.getUsername(),
                userRequest.getDisplayName(), userRequest.getEmail(), userRequest.getIdentityProvider());

        Set<String> strRoles = userRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);

                        break;
                    case "mod":
                        Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(modRole);

                        break;
                    default:
                        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }
        user.setRoles(roles);
        user.setId(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        user.setLastLoggedOn(new Date());
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
}
```

The weird issue is that I have other endpoints and they are working fine, the users rest api is the one not being found. I have added tool in the api as it is the name of the war file, I have multiple war files running on the tomcat.

ServletInitializer

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MonitoringToolApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.tool.demo.controller"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.tool.demo.model")
public class MonitoringToolApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MonitoringToolApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Example</name>
    <description>example</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.properties file

```
 #Example Tool connection string
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=example_tools
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password= user2k!!__
    
    ## Hibernate Properties
    # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    
    # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
```

Please help me out with the issue. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the project configuration file

Comment: Hi @HaiZi have added my pom file

Comment: No, I'm talking about the application.properties file

Comment: Hi @HaiZi i have added

Comment: are you hitting with post body? if you simply hit enpoint url they that ll be GET call so please use SoapUI or Postman then select POST metthod and provide requestbody then hit

Answer (score 0):

When deploying the project on the server side, exclude the embedded tomcat in the pom.xml file

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```